# How do I set proxy for terminal?

Tags: command-line, proxy

I am using Lantern Proxy to open blocked websites. it's running on

```
http://localhost:44813
```

It works on Chrome well, but I want to set on Terminal. So I've run following commands:

```
export https_proxy='http://localhost:44813/'
export http_proxy='http://localhost:44813/'
```

and when I run

```
env | grep -i proxy
```

I see:

```
HTTP_PROXYs=http://localhost:44813/
NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1
http_proxy=http://localhost:44813/
https_proxy=http://localhost:44813/
HTTPS_PROXY=http://localhost:44813/
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1
HTTP_PROXY=http://localhost:44813/
```

But I can't ping any blocked website!! how can I solve it?

Comment: `ping` is not `http` or `https`, so setting these proxies should have no effect on that. Don't try to `ping`. Try to actually fetch web pages, it should work.

Comment: but when I ping unblocked site i have ping and it replyed. I just can't ping blocked websites!!

Comment: Cross-posted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/428024/70524

Comment: "I just can't ping blocked websites!!" – this matches the very definition of "blocked", doesn't it? :-) By having a http(s) proxy, you find a different, unblocked route for http(s), but not for ping.

Comment: Ping is not HTTP. Ping is in fact not even TCP. It's a protocol called ICMP. In addition, bypassing a proxy in your setup is **trivial**. If you want a filtering proxy, you probably don't want the clients to have a route to the Internet, but rather force them to go trough your proxy.

Answer (score 3):

The name "http proxy" implies that it is only for http/https. Using a http-proxy has no influence on the operation of other protocols.

Ping is part of ICMP and only works when you can reach the target host via IP, i.E. it is not blocked by some kind of firewall.